# My multi-threading process does not work correctly

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, output

I would like to perform batch processing for my large dataset. I want to run `n` **thread** in parallel to process every batch of `n` data samples. Here is a simulation with a simple function:

```
from threading import Thread
import queue
def funct(i, a, b, out_que):
    res = {}
    res[i] = a+b
    out_que.put(res)

# I try to run 3 threads in parallel, 5 times
res_list = []
for i in range(5):
    threads = []
    res_queue = queue.Queue()
    for j in range(3):
         thread = Thread(target=funct, args=(j, 5, 6, res_queue))
         thread.start()
         threads.append(thread)
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
    resulted = res_queue.get()
    res_list.append(resulted)
print(res_list)
```

I want to get the following result:

```
[{0: 11}, {1: 11}, {2: 11}, {3: 11}, {4: 11}, {5: 11}, {6: 11}, {7: 11}, {8: 11}, {9: 11}, {10: 11}, {11: 11}, {12: 11}, {13: 11}, {14: 11}]
```

But, I got this:

```
[{0: 11}, {0: 11}, {0: 11}, {0: 11}, {0: 11}]
```

Comment: that's not how you instantiate Thread. it should be Thread(target=funct,args=(j,5,6,res_queue)).

Comment: Also be aware that thread parallelism will not generally accelerate your process because the GIL will only run one thread at once; unless your target function is releasing the GIL (in an I/O operation for example), it will take more or less the same time to process your data

Comment: I updated the code, but it's still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get only one element from your queue `res_queue.get()`. Change this part

```
resulted = res_queue.get()
res_list.append(resulted)
```

to something like this

```
resulted = []
while not res_queue.empty():
    res_list.append(res_queue.get())
```

To get such result `[{0: 11}, {1: 11}, {2: 11}, {3: 11}, {4: 11}, {5: 11}, {6: 11}, {7: 11}, {8: 11}, {9: 11}, {10: 11}, {11: 11}, {12: 11}, {13: 11}, {14: 11}]` you need to pass `5*i + j` instead of `j` in `args=(j, 5, 6, res_queue)`.